# Complex Trig Equations

Tags: trigonometry

Can I please get help for the following question?

Solve for all values of $x$ in radians for $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \sin 2x$.

I got up to 
$$\sin (x+\pi/4) = 2 \sin x \cos x$$
 after using auxiliary angles and double angle identities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

and $$\sin y=\sin A\implies y=m\pi+(-1)^mA $$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt2 \sin(2x)$$
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt2} + \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt2} = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x)\cos(\pi/4) + \cos(x)\sin(\pi/4) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x+\pi/4) = \sin(2x)$$
Which is where you got to
$$\sin(2x)-\sin(x+\pi/4)=0$$
$$2\sin(\frac{x-\pi/4}{2})\cos(\frac{3x+\pi/4}{2})=0$$

Therefore, either $\sin(\frac{x-\pi/4}{2}) = 0$ or $\cos(\frac{3x+\pi/4}{2})=0$

$$x-\pi/4 = 2(0+2\pi k), k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$x= \pi/4 + 4\pi k$$
$$3x+\pi/4 = 2(\pi/2 + 2\pi k)$$
$$ x= 3\pi/12 + 4\pi k/3$$